# Abrir datepicker desde edittext

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Tengo configurado un datepicker para que al pulsar un edittext este se abra para poder introducir la fecha:

Inicio las variables a 0:

```
private var mYearAct = 0
private var mMonthAct: Int = 0
private var mDayAct: Int = 0
private lateinit var fechaActual: TextView
```

Configuro el datepicker:

```
fechaActual = findViewById(R.id.Date_Ult_Taller)
   

    //datepicker fecha actual
    findViewById<View>(R.id.Date_Ult_Taller)
        .setOnClickListener {
            val c = Calendar.getInstance()
            mYearAct = c[Calendar.YEAR]
            mMonthAct = c[Calendar.MONTH]
            mDayAct = c[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH]
            val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
                this,
                { _: DatePicker?, year: Int, monthOfYear: Int, dayOfMonth: Int ->
                    fechaActual.text =
                        dayOfMonth.toString() + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year
                }, mYearAct, mMonthAct, mDayAct
            )
            datePickerDialog.show()
        }
```

Esta es la config del XML:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/Date_Ult_Taller"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:maxLength="7"
            android:background="@drawable/borde_editext"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/calendar_icon_178065"
            android:editable="false"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            android:hint="@string/ejFechaAct"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColorHint="@color/letragrisclaro"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TuCocheAlDia"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck,TextContrastCheck" />
```

Con esta configuración cuando hago click la primera vez sobre el edittext se abre el teclado y cuando pulso una segunda se abre el datepicker.
¿Qué atributo debo establecer para que el datepicker se muestre la primera vez que hago click y además evitar que se abra el teclado evitándonos escribir?(A poder ser en el XML). Gracias!

Comment: Debe agregar el atributo android:focusable="false" para lograr lo que necesitas. Ya que cuando le da click el EditText interpreta que vas escribir y es por eso que reacciona en el segundo click

Comment: Funciona. Muchas gracias amigo!